# Split a String Array and Store Values for each Iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So the variable `classList` stores all classes for the body. I then created a variable `classListLength` that has the length of `classList` so I can iterate through each index and then split each class. I do not know how to store the splits for each index as it loops through `classList`. Help me please.

```
var classList = jQuery('body').attr('class').split(' ');
var classListLength = classList.length;

var keyWords = function(array) {
for (var i = 0; i < classListLength; i++ ) {
  classList[i].split('-');
 }
}
```

if i do the following in the console

```
var keyWords = function(array) {
for (var i = 0; i < classListLength; i++ ) {
  console.log(classList[i].split('-'));
 }
}
```

I can see exactly what I want but I want to be able to store that and check it later on with a conditional.

Comment: You already have a `classList` property of the `body` element. What is the purpose of all this hassle. Just do `body.classList` and `body.classList.length` to access that classList array and it's length.

Comment: Yeah I realized I was complicating it a bit more. What I ended up doing was using the `.includes` method to search for a particular keyword within the class I was looking for. Still alot to learn for me but I muscled through it.

Comment: You better don't do a search over a string with `.includes`. You might get false positive results if the string your are searching for is a sub-string of another class' name. You search it over `classList` property of the DOM element by `element.classList.includes("classname");`

Comment: I cant use "classname" as I dont know what it will be. I need to search a sub-string of that class, the whole class itself is not really important as to the substring of it. Or maybe im not understanding you clearly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var splitClassList = classList.map(function (class) {
  return class.split('-');
});
```

Comment: This will result in a SyntaxError as class is a reserved word

Answer (score 0):

So I solved what I needed. The below code allows me to iterate through my split classList. I then check the the specific class I want within the classList using `.includes` method and execute what I need done. If you guys know how to make this a bit more modular please chime in.

```
var brandClass

// Iterate though split classes
jQuery.each( classList, function(i) {
 if ( classList[i].includes('product-wildridge') ) {
 brandClass = classList[i];
}
});

// check specific class for certin keywords
var customTab = function(brandClass) {
 if (brandClass.includes('wildridge') && brandClass.includes('deep') ) {
 return true;
} else {
jQuery('#tab-fabric').css('display', 'none');
 }
}

customTab(brandClass);
```